# How to doctor my CPU utilization issue, I am using ubuntu ec2 instance with nginx, uwsgi and django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

Hello I am running an EC2 ubuntu instance (3 instances to be exact with a loadbalancer) this morning I realized that all 3 of my instances are running at 100% cpu utilization and that worries me, they're usually running below 40% unless I have scheduled task happening all at once. They are all running nginx, uwsgi, celery, and django.

This has never happened to me before so I am not sure how I should approach it. What I have done so far:

- Restart instances
- Stop and start instances
- Unload and reload balancers
- Restart supervisorctl

Usually these actions would regulate my cpu utilization but this time they just keep shooting back up. Any hints where I should start?

**EDIT:** After running `ps -aux`:

```
ubuntu    1515 90.4  0.8 386156 147604 ?       R    20:02  38:06 /opt/django/www/bin/python /opt/d
ubuntu    1517  0.0  0.6 555196 101404 ?       S    20:02   0:01 /opt/django/www/bin/python /opt/d
ubuntu    1518 88.7  0.9 387968 149864 ?       R    20:02  37:23 /opt/django/www/bin/python /opt/d
ubuntu    1519  0.0  0.6 555568 101636 ?       S    20:02   0:01 /opt/django/www/bin/python /opt/d
ubuntu    1520 90.1  0.9 388984 150876 ?       R    20:02  38:00 /opt/django/www/bin/python /opt/d
ubuntu    1521 90.3  0.9 401572 163092 ?       R    20:02  38:04 /opt/django/www/bin/python /opt/d
```

Comment: Did you look at all the processes to see what is using all that cpu? `ps -aux`

Comment: Added through edit. It seems like python is causing it to spike?

Comment: Looks like you have a Python process running which is consuming all the CPU, have you checked the process as to what it is doing? Do you have some long running process/task configured as part of supervisorctl which is getting kicked off when you reboot the system? My suggestion is to kill all the Python processes and see if there are any other process which is causing the spike. What is the Load Average? Is the server being bombarded with API calls?

Comment: I apologize beforehand as I would not know how to check the process and which ones are running. I am quite new as I only knew how to set everything up and get it running. Even when I rebooted the system the process was still running. During this time we held off on making any API calls. Thank you, again.